# Can Hive Read data from Delta lake file format?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I started going through DELTA LAKE file format, is hive capable of reading data from this newly introduced delta file format? If so could you please let me know the serde you were using.

Comment: All data in Delta Lake is stored in Apache Parquet format, Hive has a plugin for this, more info in the readme at https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr

Comment: Checkout this issue: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/85

Answer (score 1):

Hive support is available with Delta Lake file format. First, step is to add the jars from https://github.com/delta-io/connectors, in our hive path. And then create a table using following format.
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test.dl_attempts_stream
    (
    ...
    ) 
    STORED BY 'io.delta.hive.DeltaStorageHandler'
    LOCATION

Delta Format picks up partition by default, so no need to mention partition while creating a table.

> NOTE: If data is being inserted via a Spark job, please provide hive-site.xml, and enableHiveSupport in Spark Job, to create Delta Lake table in Hive.